# What does "straight to smashing" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, slang

> Tinder is like Facebook, but it's just, like, straight to smashing.

What does "straight to smashing" mean?

I tried to find answer following below step, but it doesn't make sense. Please, help me.

1. It's straight to smashing.
2. straight : frank
3. smash : to go to pieces suddenly under collision or pressure
4. It's frank to going to pieces?????????
5. I can't even understand the literal meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tinder is, like Facebook, a social media site, but oriented toward making *new* connections; it is consequently used mostly as a dating service.

*Straight* here is used in the sense "directly, immediately, by the shortest route".

*Smash* has recently accrued a new slang meaning, "have sex"—it's a relatively inoffensive way to say *fuck*.

So you may paraphrase your sentence as:

> Tinder is like Facebook but enables its users to move more directly toward sexual encounters.

Comment: Wow.. Ty. I never thought smashing = fuck!!!!

Comment: @TINGCHOE Neither did I! --but it was pretty obvious that that was what it *had* to mean, so I just Googled around and confirmed it in about 45 seconds.

Comment: See also: banging, pounding, grinding, mashing, bashing, biffing, bopping...

Answer (score 1):

Not saying Stoney is wrong because I have never been to Tinder, but could **straight to smashing** also mean *shortest route to excellence/the best result*?

> smash·ing
>
> adjective BRITISH informal excellent; wonderful. "you look smashing!"

Google Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

That phrase was specifically from episode 1 of the show Man seeking Woman and for 3 seasons the character that said it said smashing to mean having sex so, no, it doesn't have any other meaning. Watch the show and you will know what i mean.

Comment: I agree, but we'd like to see some reference, even if urban or slang dictionaries are all you can find.